# Change the DOM based on a drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to do something hackerish and not sure how to go about doing it.

I'm injecting a dropdown menu onto a web page

```
var myObj = $("<form action='action_page.php'>" +
    "<select name='cars'>" +
    "<option value='volvo'>Volvo</option>" +
    "<option value='saab'>Saab</option>" + 
    "<option value='fiat'>Fiat</option>" +
    "<option value='audi'>Audi</option>" +
    "</select>" +
    "</form>")

$('.location').append(myObj)
```

I'll be setting the initial option value when the page is loaded based off of some other data.

So for example, I'm looking through car profiles and some backend service guesses the type of car.

When the page is loaded, the dropdown value is set to `Volvo`. However, it was incorrect and it's actually a `Saab`. So, I change the option on the dropdown menu to `Saab`.

Is there a way to reflect this change in the DOM **without** having to hit a submit button?

Comment: You need an event listener to do something when the drop-down changes

Comment: any suggestions where I can read / learn more about that?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_eventlistener.asp

Comment: This isn't very "hackerish", it's very common in web page design.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an event listener with jQuery:

```
$('.location').append(myObj)
$('select[name=cars]').change(function() {
    var selectedCar = $(this).val();
    // update DOM based on selectedCar
});
```

Comment: is there a way to have access to selectedCar outside the function?

Comment: You can assign it to a global variable.

Comment: You can also pass it as an argument to another function. There's nothing special about it, you can use it just like any other variable.

Comment: oh right, ok. $(this) was what I was looking for! thank you